# ngIf check if object is empty [done]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

i have a list name "day".

```
export class Day{
    id:number;
    name: string;
    items: Object;
}
```

i want to display "Hello" when items is empty. I try to used *ngIf but it doesn't work.
This is my code.

```
<div class=" list" *ngFor="let day of days">
    <div class="list-name">
        <strong>
            {{day.name}}
        </strong>
        <div *ngIf= "day.items === 0">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of day.items">
        <div class="column" [style.background-image]="'url(' + item.photoPath + ')'">
            <h4 class="item-name">{{item.name}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div *ngIf= "!day || day?.items?.length === 0">`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Looking at the code items is some kind of array, badly typed as Object. Did you try to use date.items.length? Did you debug your code and inspected the variables?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

As I seem items is not an array. It is an object. Using ngFor over an Object would resuslt in an error.

Secondly, you should use .length over an array to get the count of Objects. so it should be as,

```
<div *ngIf= "day?.items?.length === 0">
```

Comment: I would also add the option to check weither it exists - *ngIf="day.items && day.items.length === 0"

Comment: Zem  i recommend  you use safe navigation operator too  `*ngIf= "day?.items.length === 0">` or check `<div *ngIf= "!day || day?.items?.length === 0">`

Comment: @ZemZem this is the safe navigation operator question mark `?` here is the link to offical doc : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

Answer (score 0):

You have to use length to check the array size

```
<div *ngIf= "day.items?.length === 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div *ngIf= "day.items.length === 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<div *ngIf= "day.items == null || day.items.length === 0">` for check items is null or empty.

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scssrw

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make use of conditional statement expression inside your interpolation without using 'ngIf'.

```
...
<strong>
   {{ (day.item && day.item?.length) ? day.name : day.name + 'Hello' }}
</strong>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question is about finding the length of object that is only possible using Object.keys(myObj).length. In Angular you can use it as:

in .ts file:

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

in html file:

```
<div *ngIf="objectKeys(myObj).length > 0"></div>
```

Here is the reference:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-length-xzxajl?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.